# Designing a chatbot to ask the right questions in order to guess an object

Tags: chatbot

I am trying to design a chatbot to ask minimal amount of questions to guess an object a human user in mind

Lets suppose I have a database as such

```
Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Label
1  0  0  1  Apple
0  0  0  1  Apple
0  1  1  1  Mango
```

Where Q1 is "Is it red in color", Q2 is "Is it soft?", Q4 is "Is it sweet". There can be thousands possible questions, and thousands label possible in real database.

The chatbot will ask a question
A user will answer yes or no.

A user starts this game by having apple in mind
Chatbot asked the first question "Is it red"?
Human: yes
Chatbot calculate the probability so far. Apple 60%, Mango 0%
Since apple now has the highest probability, it will ask a question that help to see if it is really apple, "Is it sweet"? 
Human: yes
Chatbot update the probability. Apple 90%. Mango 40%
Once the probability is high enough, the chatbot will stop and spit out all the probability it has

First question: I need to get the probability of each label with only a few questions answered. Say after I ask the first question "Is it red". Chatbot needs to know probability of each item given what we know so far
60% = Prob(Apple, [1 ? ? ?])
I am not quite sure how to feed in a feature vector with unknowns to the model and ask it to predict

Second question: I want to ask least amount of questions, so ideally I would like to ask a question that can really differentiate. How do I determine which next question to ask.

Seems like the traditional machine learning model does not work. How would you design a system like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. The answer is naive bayes. 
The math can be found [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html)
x is a feature
y is the object in question

```
while (True):
  # sort the object based on probability
  # print out the objects with their probability
  # top_object = object with highest probability
  # Get the x such that P(x=1|top_object) is the highest, and ask "do that object have x"
  # Wait for input from user 
  # Then for each object, update probability prob = prob * P(x=input|y)
  # remove x from possible feature can ask
  # if no more feature left, quit
```